# Atom file tree colors

Tags: atom-editor

On the Atom text editor what do the different file tree colors stand for. My files are in 3 different colors: black, green, and orange. Black files do not run properly while green runs fine. If anyone knows what the colors specifically mean, please let me know.

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/file-tree-colors-what-do-they-mean/12770/2

Answer (score 6):

The color refers to their (or, in the case of folders, their descendants’) Git status: orange for modified, green for new, red for deleted.